# XSLT: How to fetch multiple nodes dynamically based on an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I got stuck while creating an XSLT to interpret this XML. I hope someone can help me cracking this.

The simplified XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<debtors>
    <debtor>
        <debtor_number>1234</debtor_number>
        <name>Debtor name</name>
        <userfield id="1">Value1</userfield>
        <userfield id="2">Value2</userfield>
    </debtor>
</debtors>
```

My current XSLT look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="debtors">
        <debtors>
            <xsl:for-each select="debtor">
                <debtor>
                    <debtor_number>
                        <xsl:value-of select="debtor_number"/>
                    </debtor_number>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </name>
                    <userfields>
                        <xsl:for-each select="userfield[@id]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>                      
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </userfields>
                </debtor>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </debtors>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This result in this:

| debtor number | name | userfields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Debtor name | Value1Value2 |

However the desired result is:
| debtor number | name        | userfield1 |userfield2 |
|---------------|-------------|------------|-----------|
| 1234          | Debtor name | Value1     | Value2    |

I know an easy way for this simple example is to do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="debtors">
        <debtors>
            <xsl:for-each select="debtor">
                <debtor>
                    <debtor_number>
                        <xsl:value-of select="debtor_number"/>
                    </debtor_number>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </name>
                    <userfield1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="userfield[@id='1']"/>
                    </userfield1>
                    <userfield2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="userfield[@id='2']"/>
                    </userfield2>
                </debtor>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </debtors>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately for me there are going to be a lot of userfields in the actual XML file, which then all would have to be defined individually in the XSLT. Furthermore new userfields could be added later on, hence I would like to use a more dynamic approach to this. Any help with this would be appreciated greatly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your stylesheet is producing an XML output. Why don't you show the expected  result as XML, instead of a cryptic and ambiguous table representation?

Comment: the reason for this is that it needs to be picked up by an outdated import tool which can only work with csv styles data unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/debtors">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="debtor">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="debtor_number | name"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="userfield[@id]">
                    <xsl:element name="userfield{@id}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>                      
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes Michael, that was exactly what I was looking for. You are my hero now!!!